# disabling cookies in chrome and IE using Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to disable cookies in chrome and IE using Webdriver.

for chrome - 
I am trying the following code with no success-

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-local-storage"));
```

for IE - no idea

However I was able to disable for firefox using following code-

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile(allElements[1]);

ffprofile.setPreference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2);
```

Comment: Still searching solution for IE.Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

The following disables cookies in Chrome:

```
WebDriver driver;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();   
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.cookies", 2);  
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally got the solution for IE also. You cant do it through webdriver but u need to edit registry through Java

to disable cookie

```
String command = "REG ADD \"HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\      \" /v 1A10 /t REG_DWORD /d 0X3 /f";  
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

to enable cookie

```
String command = "REG ADD \"HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\      \" /v 1A10 /t REG_DWORD /d 0X1 /f";  
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```